Chromium browser -- Easy Script -- NOT Working
I am using ubuntu 24.04. I have download the chromium-browser script from
https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/#easy-script-to-download-and-run-latest-linux-build
but after running the script update-and-run.sh, I am unable to open the browser.
I have installed in the folder /opt/softwares/chromium-latest-linux-master/
and run the script.
I have given the folowing command to open the chromium
all-au@all-au:/opt/softwares/chromium-latest-linux-master/chrome-linux$ ./chrome
[6340:6340:1001/133148.426630:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(128)] No usable sandbox! If you are running on Ubuntu 23.10+ or another Linux distro that has disabled unprivileged user namespaces with AppArmor, see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/security/apparmor-userns-restrictions.md. Otherwise see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the (older) SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
#0 0x5abf0cb6c182 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x5abf0cb5983e base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x5abf0cab053a logging::LogMessage::Flush()
#3 0x5abf0cab1019 logging::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
#4 0x5abf0ab43a7e content::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#5 0x5abf0be66c7c content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#6 0x5abf0be64ad1 content::RunContentProcess()
#7 0x5abf0be64ef7 content::ContentMain()
#8 0x5abf07937380 ChromeMain
#9 0x78fbe302a1ca (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2a1c9)
#10 0x78fbe302a28b __libc_start_main
#11 0x5abf0793702a _start
Crash keys:
  "num-switches" = "0"
  "osarch" = "x86_64"
  "pid" = "6340"
  "ptype" = "browser"

Received signal 6
#0 0x5abf0cb6c182 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x5abf0cb5983e base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x5abf0cb6bb91 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#3 0x78fbe3045320 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x4531f)
#4 0x78fbe309eb1c pthread_kill
#5 0x78fbe304526e gsignal
#6 0x78fbe30288ff abort
#7 0x5abf0cab0eea logging::LogMessage::HandleFatal()
#8 0x5abf0cab0ac7 logging::LogMessage::Flush()
#9 0x5abf0cab1019 logging::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
#10 0x5abf0ab43a7e content::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#11 0x5abf0be66c7c content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#12 0x5abf0be64ad1 content::RunContentProcess()
#13 0x5abf0be64ef7 content::ContentMain()
#14 0x5abf07937380 ChromeMain
#15 0x78fbe302a1ca (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2a1c9)
#16 0x78fbe302a28b __libc_start_main
#17 0x5abf0793702a _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 0000000000000000 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 0000000000000006 r13: 00000000000004e8 r14: 0000000000000016 r15: 00007ffc4eb04af8
  di: 00000000000018c4  si: 00000000000018c4  bp: 00007ffc4eb03520  bx: 00000000000018c4
  dx: 0000000000000006  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 000078fbe309eb1c  sp: 00007ffc4eb034e0
  ip: 000078fbe309eb1c efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Aborted (core dumped)```

The browser is not opening.
Kindly help. Your help is much appreciated.

